# I can not use mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I do a lot of research on the results of the work, but does not work

my .bash_profile

[image]

I use xampp and mac os sierra

[image]

Error ;

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is the probelm?why you can not dump?

Comment: Error : 
Command not found error

Comment: You should put the `bin` path in the `$PATH` variable, not the path to the executable itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `.bashrc` replace:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysqldump
```

for the following:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
```

Also remember to open a new console to try the `mysqldump` since an already open one won't get the correct `PATH`